# clearing contents of a RelativeLayout programmatically - android java

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I am dynamically adding ImageViews to a RelativeLayout depending on user input.  I have also created a button that when pressed, should clear all of the content of that RelativeLayout (remove all children).  I was hoping for a .clear() method, but no such luck.

can someone point me in the right direction here?

```
RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.iv_section);
rel.SomethingToRemoveAllChildren();
```

thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ViewGroup.removeAllViews()

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout yourLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutId);
yourLayout.removeAllViews();